# What is a series about wizards with yarn magic?

Tags: story-identification, magic

I barely remember this series and don't expect anyone else to, but it's worth a shot.

All I remember is 4 or 5 wizards: one had yarn magic, one had fire or lightning, and I remember one of them had living bronze on her hand. I also remember the yarn one made a circle of yarn with a ball of each of their magic in it to bind them together.

Comment: Was this TV, movies, books, short stories, comics or something else. When did you encounter it? Can you estimate when it was released?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the channel by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This is the *[Circle of Magic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Magic)* series by Tamora Pierce.

> Circle of Magic is a quartet of fantasy novels by Tamora Pierce, set in Emelan, a fictional realm in a pseudo-medieval and renaissance era. It revolves around four young mages, each specializing in a different kind of magic, as they learn to control their extraordinary and strong powers and put them to use. It is followed by another quartet, The Circle Opens, which takes place four years later, and the standalone book The Will of the Empress, which takes place several years after that. Melting Stones and Battle Magic are also set in the same universe, but they feature only Briar.

Sandry has the thread magic that ultimately binds them together. Daja has smithing magic and gains living bronze skin on her hand. Tris controls elements like lightning. The last member is Briar who has plant magic.

The scene where she makes a circle of yarn with their magic in it is near the end of the first book, *Sandry's Book*. They had been trapped in an earthquake, and her binding their magic together allowed them to work together, using all of their talents together to save them.

> Sandry's first act, once home, was to put her green drop spindle on a shelf. Beside it she placed the thread with four lumps in it. It had somehow woven its loose ends together as she had spun it underground, and now it formed a ring. There was no way even to tell where the loose ends had met: the circle was complete, the four lumps equally spaced.

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242207/young-adult-fantasy-about-children-living-with-an-elderly-woman-and-learning-mag